# $date + 1 year?

Tags: php, strtotime

I'm trying to get a date that is one year from the date I specify.

My code looks like this:

```
$futureDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+one year', $startDate));
```

It's returning the wrong date. Any ideas why?

Comment: You forgot to tell about the error.

Comment: Frank Farmer: are you so certain? I would rather wait for OP's retifications/comments.

Comment: In my haste to post this last night I forgot to clarify - it was returning the wrong date. Sorry! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Use it like this instead strtotime('+1 year', $startDate));

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To add one year to todays date use the following:

```
$oneYearOn = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", mktime()) . " + 365 day"));
```

For the other examples you must initialize $StartingDate with a timestamp value
for example:

```
$StartingDate = mktime();  // todays date as a timestamp
```

Try this

```
$newEndingDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($StaringDate)) . " + 365 day"));
```

or

```
$newEndingDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($StaringDate)) . " + 1 year"));
```

Comment: Adding "+365" instead of "+1 year" did it. Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't this break in the event of a leap year?

Comment: As of PHP 5.1, when called with no arguments, mktime() throws an E_STRICT notice: use the time() function instead.

Comment: Downvoted here too. The number of seconds in a day, days in a year, seconds in a year, etc. are all variable. If you're interested in 'one year from now', you have to pass in an interval of 'one year'. Subdividing on your own is what leads to errors around leap days and leap seconds and daylight savings changes. Worse, it causes flappy unit tests.

Comment: why my answer is downvoted ??

$addedoneyear=date("y")+1; //for adding one year

whats wrong with it ?

Comment: Downvoted, because it isn't accounting for leap year.

Comment: What about if the next year is a leap year but I want to get the same date for the next year?

Comment: This doesn't even come close to working. There's a typo in `$StartingDate` in two places (calling it `$StaringDate`). Also, calling strtotime on `$StartingDate`, which is _already_ a timestamp since it was created with mktime(), returns false, which makes it return the wrong date. Why are you calling strtotime on a timestamp? Also, mktime() should now be time() as of PHP 5.1. Did this answer ever work for anyone or is it just really outdated?

Comment: Deprecated: mktime(): You should be using the time() function instead

Answer (score 259):

```
$futureDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

$futureDate is one year from now!

```
$futureDate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($startDate)) );
```

$futureDate is one year from $startDate!

Comment: Please note that if $startDate is already a timestamp (such as one created earlier with the time() or mktime() function) and not a string, you should not wrap it in strtotime or it will not work. Instead, do `$futureDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 year',$startDate));` as K Prime mentioned below.

Answer (score 15):

```
//1 year from today's date
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+1 year'));

//1 year from from specific date
echo date('22-09-Y', strtotime('+1 year'));
```

hope this simpler bit of code helps someone in future :)

Answer (score 9):

Try: `$futureDate=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 year',$startDate));`

Comment: While that does return the right answer, the other one does not actually return an error either... just the wrong date.

Comment: strtotime doesn't throw errors.  It returns false in the case of an error.

Comment: PHP will throw warnings if the default timezone is not set... though apparently that is not what he meant

Comment: I was getting error on your code I changed `,` to `.` and it worked `date("Y-m-d",strtotime('+1 year '.$startDate))`;

Answer (score 7):

I just had the same problem, however calling `date()` twice and incrementing the year seems simplest solution to me.

```
echo (date('Y') + 1) . date('-m-d');
```

Comment: Great, I use it to get the next year: `$next_year = (date('Y')+1)`.

Answer (score 7):

```
// Declare a variable for this year 
$this_year = date("Y");
// Add 1 to the variable
$next_year = $this_year + 1;
$year_after = $this_year + 2;

// Check your code
    echo "This year is ";
    echo $this_year;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "Next year is ";
    echo $next_year;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "The year after that is ";
    echo $year_after;
```

Answer (score 7):

I prefer the OO approach:

```
$date = new \DateTimeImmutable('today'); //'today' gives midnight, leave blank for current time.
$futureDate = $date->add(\DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 Year'))
```

Use `DateTimeImmutable` otherwise you will modify the original date too!
more on DateTimeImmutable: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php

---

If you just want from todays date then you can always do:

```
new \DateTimeImmutable('-1 Month');
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PHP 5.3, it is because you need to set the default time zone:

```
date_default_timezone_set()
```

Answer (score 3):

`strtotime()` is returning `bool(false)`, because it can't parse the string `'+one year'` (it doesn't understand "one").  `false` is then being implicitly cast to the `integer` timestamp `0`.  It's a good idea to verify `strtotime()`'s output isn't `bool(false)` before you go shoving it in other functions.

[From the docs:](https://www.php.net/strtotime#function.strtotime.returnvalues)

> Return Values
>
> Returns a timestamp on success, FALSE
> otherwise. Previous to PHP 5.1.0, this
> function would return -1 on failure.

Comment: Yeah, good point. My production code will have that, but I was tearing my hair out trying to get this to work, so stripped it down to as little code as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$nextyear  = date("M d,Y",mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m",strtotime($startDate)),   date("d",strtotime($startDate)),   date("Y",strtotime($startDate))+1));
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a simpler and less sophisticated solution:

```
$monthDay = date('m/d');
$year = date('Y')+1;
$oneYearFuture = "".$monthDay."/".$year."";
echo"The date one year in the future is: ".$oneYearFuture."";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use strtotime() to get future time.

```
//strtotime('+1 day');
//strtotime('+1 week');
//strtotime('+1 month');

 $now = date('Y-m-d'); 
 $oneYearLaterFromNow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year'));
 $oneYearLaterFromAnyDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 year', strtotime($anyValidDateString)));
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case (i want to add 3 years to current date) the solution was:

```
$future_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("now + 3 years"));
```

To Gardenee, Treby and Daniel Lima:
what will happen with 29th February? Sometimes February has only 28 days :)

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: `date('Y-m-d', time()-60*60*24*365);`

You can make it more "readable" with defines:

```
define('ONE_SECOND', 1);
define('ONE_MINUTE', 60 * ONE_SECOND);
define('ONE_HOUR',   60 * ONE_MINUTE);
define('ONE_DAY',    24 * ONE_HOUR);
define('ONE_YEAR',  365 * ONE_DAY);

date('Y-m-d', time()-ONE_YEAR);
```

Answer (score -1):

I wanted 1 year range only for an HTML5 Date input. This is what worked for me:

```
   <input type="date"

           min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d"); ?>"

           max="<?php echo date((intval(date("Y"))+1)."-m-d"); ?>"
    />
```

1 Year from now:

```
date((intval(date("Y"))+1)."-m-d");
```

Comment: This advice was [given on this page in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700447/2943403). Please only post a new answer if you have something unique and valuable to share.

Comment: I didn't see that. Not sure why this deserves a negative comment. The latter code actually gives a programming mistake warning of "Wrong string concatenation operator ". I believe adding intval is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: My comment was not a negative comment -- it was a clear and educational comment. 
 I wonder if you'd have been happier for me to dv without any kind of feedback at all -- I consider that to be trollish/unhelpful behaviour. `intval()` is not needed in the other answer. https://3v4l.org/UINRv

Comment: Without adding intval it actually affects performace. If you are writing bad code then yes its not needed lol.