# PHP date + 1 year is returning a date slightly less than 1 year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I've coded a user membership plugin which is supposed to generate a membership expiry date for the member to be 1 year from the date that they sign up.  To calculate this date I have the following line of code:

```
$oneYearOn = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date('Y-m-d', time()) . ' + 1 year'));
```

However, in some instances, this seems to be returning a date slightly less than 1 year.  For example, we just had a member sign up on 2021-09-27, but the expiry date got set to 2022-09-15.  12 days short of what it should be.

Any ideas why this has happened?

Comment: Hi ! Does it answer to your question or not ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14524760/4698373

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't see how you could lose 12 days except if the year were 1752, when much of the world switched from the Julian to Gregorian calendar.